# How to automatically free up port 8080 with Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, server

Im running basic Spring Boot MVC app and on each app restart, I have to manually shut down port 8080 otherwise Spring boot application will not run It gives this error:

```
Execution failed for task ':DemoApplication.main()'.
> Process 'command 'C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-11.0.3/bin/java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

Shouldn't Tomcat shut down and release the port 8080 soon as the app is shut down?

Comment: Where are you running it from? A jar? A war? Some IDE?

Comment: Im running it in IntelliJ. Im also using thymeleaf

Comment: Hm, that's weird, never had this issue in intellij with spring mvc. Read Intellij docs maybe...

Comment: I changed the port to 8081,  still the same. Its definitely that its app running on these ports, nothing else.

Comment: Are you using app-maven-plugin? If so, try running 'appengine:run' instead of 'appengine:start'.

Comment: Im not using app-maven-plugin. Its a gradle project.

Answer (score 0):

In IntelliJ go to Run / Edit Configurations... / Tomcat Server / Local / Shutdown script ans specify a script you use to free the port there.

Alternatively, you can edit the original Tomcat configuration, for example at `d:\dev\apache-tomcat-8.0.36\conf\server.xml`, like so: `<Server port="8080" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">`.